# Certificate of K3S cluster

Tags: docker, k3s

I'm using a K3S Cluster in a docker(-compose) container in my CI/CD pipeline, to test my application code. However I have problem with the certificate of the cluster. I need to communicate on the cluster using the external addres. My docker-compose script looks as follows

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: rancher/k3s:v0.8.1
    command: server --disable-agent 
    environment:
    - K3S_CLUSTER_SECRET=somethingtotallyrandom
    - K3S_KUBECONFIG_OUTPUT=/output/kubeconfig.yaml
    - K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE=666
    volumes:
    - k3s-server:/var/lib/rancher/k3s
    # get the kubeconfig file
    - .:/output
    ports:
#    - 6443:6443
     - 6080:6080
     - 192.168.2.110:6443:6443

  node:
    image: rancher/k3s:v0.8.1
    tmpfs:
    - /run
    - /var/run
    privileged: true
    environment:
    - K3S_URL=https://server:6443
    - K3S_CLUSTER_SECRET=somethingtotallyrandom
    ports:
      - 31000-32000:31000-32000

volumes:
  k3s-server: {}
```

accessing the cluster from python gives me

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.2.110', port=6443): Max retries exceeded with url: /apis/batch/v1/namespaces/mlflow/jobs?pretty=True (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname '192.168.2.110' doesn't match either of 'localhost', '172.19.0.2', '10.43.0.1', '172.23.0.2', '172.18.0.2', '172.23.0.3', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', '172.18.0.3', '172.20.0.2'")))
```

Here are my two (three) question

- how can I add additional IP adresses to the cert generation? I was hoping the `--bind-address` in the server command triggers taht
- how can I fall back on http providing an `--http-listen-port` didn't achieve the expected result
- any other suggestion how I can enable communication with the cluster

changing the python code is not really an option as I would like o keep the code unaltered for testing. (Fallback on http works via kubeconfig.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the parameter `tls-san`

```
server --disable-agent --tls-san 192.168.2.110
```